# Python Stemming words in a File

Tags: python, nltk, stemming

I want to do stemming in a file. When I use it in terminal it works fine, but when I apply it in a text file, it does not work. 
Terminal code:

```
print PorterStemmer().stem_word('complications')
```

Function code:

```
def stemming_text_1():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        print text
        singles = []    

        stemmer = PorterStemmer() #problem from HERE
        for plural in text:
            singles.append(stemmer.stem(plural))
        print singles
```

Input test.txt

```
126211 crashes bookmarks runs error logged debug core bookmarks
126262 manual change crashes bookmarks propagated ion view bookmarks
```

Desired/expected output

```
126211 crash bookmark runs error logged debug core bookmark
126262 manual change crash bookmark propagated ion view bookmark
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: @njzk2 If I do PorterStemmer().stem_word('bookmarks') I get bookmark but when I read from the test.txt file, then the output does not change, it remain bookmarks. I'm assuming the problem is with the loop. Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question, please verify

Comment: is stem supposed to do the same as stem_word?

Comment: @njzk2 yes both stem.porter or stem.wordnet can be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the text into words for the stemmer to work. Currently, the variable `text` contains the whole file as one big string. The loop `for plural in text:` assigns each character in `text` to `plural`.

Try `for plural in text.split():` instead.

**[EDIT]** To get the output in the format you want, you need to read the file line by line instead of reading it all at once:

```
def stemming_text_1():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
            singles = []

            stemmer = PorterStemmer() #problem from HERE
            for plural in line.split():
                singles.append(stemmer.stem(plural))
            print ' '.join(singles)
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the stemming in each word, its stemming in each and single word. But, what if I want to print the output as mentioned in question.